# What does file version mean: lsattr -v

Tags: version, xattr, ext3

`lsattr -v` gives me the "version number" of given file(s).

What does this mean?

On Redhat 7.3, I could've sworn all the version numbers were 1 except
those I changed with `chattr -v`.

On Fedora 11, they appeared to be **random** numbers.

Setting version numbers or even having multiple versions of a file
could be very useful, so I want to understand how **"versioning"**  works in ext3.

Answer (score 4):

`lsattr -v` invokes the `EXT2_IOC_GETVERSION` ioctl for the file. This, in turn, retrieves the inode's `i_generation` field. This is a feature primarily intended for use with NFS: each time an inode gets allocated, one has to make sure it gets a new generation. Otherwise, NFS clients with stale file handles may manage to access data that weren't meant for them. ext2/ext3/ext4 allocates the generation number from a volume-global counter `s_next_generation`, which is incremented on every allocation.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer, but just a interresting find.

I played around with `lsattr -v` and it seems like each new file you create gets a unique number assigned to it. Im not sure if this is correct, my expirement is documented below.

```
$ mkdir temp                  # make a new folder
$ cd temp       
$ touch a b c d e f g         # create a lot files in that folder.
$ lsattr -v *                 # checkout those files using lsattr -v
1386486996 -------------e- a
1386486997 -------------e- b
1386486998 -------------e- c
1386486999 -------------e- d
1386487000 -------------e- e
1386487001 -------------e- f
1386487002 -------------e- g
```

This behaviour could be limited to the distribution **or** the disk format.

Comment: So it's sort of like an inode number, but it never repeats for the life of the filesystem?

Comment: OK, I used "chattr -v 1 file*" to change several files' version number. It worked (lsattr showed version 1) and the files didn't get merged into each other or anything weird. So I think this is still an open question. Is it just "we had extra space for an int in the inode", or does it have a meaning/usage/history/etc (other than NFS above)

Comment: add this to your question, by editing your question. That way more people get to see it...